# What is the problem with this Swift Code for finding the Diagonal Difference of a square array?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, logic, array-difference

I'm working on some HackerRank Problem Solving challenges. The language I am using right now is Swift. The objective is to calculate the **diagonal difference of a square array** with **n** columns and rows. The logic for the exercise is quite simple, and I've worked it out without any hiccups, the problem, however, is a Runtime Error, which occurs on running the program, `~ no response on stdout`. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Runtime Error Screenshot]

And here is my code (the `diagonalDifference()` function):

```
    func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]], n: Int) -> Int {
    // Write your code here
    var primarySum = 0
    var secondarySum = 0

    for i in 0..<n {
        primarySum += arr[i][i]
        secondarySum += arr[i][n - (i - 1)]
    }

    var diagDifference = abs(primarySum - secondarySum)

    return diagDifference
}
```

One other thing I've noticed in my time doing these challenges is that when I look up solutions in Swift in the discussions tab, most people don't include `n` as a parameter in the function. However, when I don't include`n` as a parameter, I get a runtime error.

Here is the rest of the code for reference:

```
import Foundation

/*
 * Complete the 'diagonalDifference' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
 */

func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]], n: Int) -> Int {
    // Write your code here
    var primarySum = 0
    var secondarySum = 0

    for i in 0..<n {
        primarySum += arr[i][i]
        secondarySum += arr[i][n - (i - 1)]
    }

    var diagDifference = abs(primarySum - secondarySum)

    return diagDifference
}

let stdout = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: stdout, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: stdout)!

guard let n = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

var arr = [[Int]]()

for _ in 1...n {
    guard let arrRowTemp = readLine()?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression) else { fatalError("Bad input") }

    let arrRow: [Int] = arrRowTemp.split(separator: " ").map {
        if let arrItem = Int($0) {
            return arrItem
        } else { fatalError("Bad input") }
    }

    guard arrRow.count == n else { fatalError("Bad input") }

    arr.append(arrRow)
}

guard arr.count == n else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let result = diagonalDifference(arr: arr, n: n)

fileHandle.write(String(result).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Can someone tell me what I should do about this, my function should return `diagDifference`. I'm somewhat comfortable with Swift, but there are still some parts of the code which I'm not totally clear about, such as:

```
fileHandle.write(String(result).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

My understanding of this is that the code writes a file using the call of the `diagonalDifference()` function. However, when I looked this up in the Swift documentation, I found that the `write()` method was deprecated.

Not considering this question specifically, if you could suggest any improvements to my code or logic in general, please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array out of bounds error on this line.  Think about what happens when `i` is `0`:

```
secondarySum += arr[i][n - (i - 1)]
```

Change it to:

```
secondarySum += arr[i][n - i - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I noticed this in some other submissions, but I didn't think that it could have been the problem.